# Python Keep Named Pipe Open

Tags: python, pipe, named-pipes

In bash, a named pipe can be kept open with `cat > mypipe`. How can this be done in python? This is what I have so far:

```
import subprocess
import os

if not os.path.exists("/tmp/mypipe"):
    os.mkfifo("/tmp/mypipe")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import subprocess

path = '/tmp/mypipe'
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.mkfifo(path)

with open(path, 'w') as f:
    subprocess.call(['cat'], stdout=f)
```